# How to pass coordinator time of Oozie to SLA argument nominal_time in a workflow?

Tags: time, parameters, oozie

I would like to pass the execution time of the coordinator into the SLA value of nominal time of a workflow. I pass the EL function in a property tag in the workflow and also in coordinator, but I received the message:

```
EL_ERROR No function is mapped to the name "coord:nominalTime"
```

I have tried different EL functions but the result was the same.

Which function do I need to use in order to pass the time of coordinator to the SLA argument of nominl time in the workflow?

To clarify, the SLA code snippet exists in workflow action, not in the coordinator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give you an answer without seeing your Oozie XML, but I think this is what you are asking for.

In the coordinator:

```
    <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>wf.xml</app-path>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>nominalTime</name>
                    <value>${coord:nominalTime()}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </workflow>
    </action>
```

In the workflow:

```
        <sla:info>
            <sla:nominal-time>${nominalTime}</sla:nominal-time>
        ...
        </sla:info>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But I have another issue, I call a sub-workflow through a java framework, it is triggered. So if I would like to pass the nominal time in the sub workflow, what should I do? Should I make changes in java framework? Or it is not obligatory?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your scenario.You're using a Java framework to call an Oozie workflow? That framework must have a way to pass an argument to the workflow?

Comment: Yes, I am using a java framework to call the sub - workflow, because it is triggered on specific conditions. I enabled SLAs with a certain value of nominal time and it was worked. However,I can not pass nominal time from the coordinator because they do not have direct relation. Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Because your original question was answered, you should open a new stackoverflow question and include more code context of your problem.